# Output using innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I need to output the contents of a JavaScript variable which has HTML code in it:

```
var jsVar = '<div>
<p> Sample text </p>
<img src="some image.jpg"  alt="" />
<div>';
```

I want to add it to an object on the page using `innerHTML`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

```
var element = document.getElementById("myElementId");
element.innerHTML = jsVar;
```

This is assuming you get your element via [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.getElementById); there are many ways to get elements in JavaScript besides that, like [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) (which returns an array of elements) or by listening to events on elements that pass themselves in as an argument.

Also, the way you're loading the string into jsVar won't work currently.  You either need to put it all on one line, or concatenate multiple strings, like below:

```
// Method 1
var jsVar = '<div><p> Sample text </p><img src="some image.jpg"  alt="" /><div>';

// Method 2
var jsVar = '<div>' +
    '<p> Sample text </p>' +
    '<img src="some image.jpg"  alt="" />' +
    '<div>';
```

Comment: I am getting a unterminated string exception. How do I remove the line feeds,spaces etc ?

Comment: If you're loading jsVar the way you wrote above, then the error you're getting is because the string is being defined over multiple lines.  You need to either have that whole string defined on one line, or concatenate multiple strings on each line.  I'll edit my answer to show you how.

Answer (score 2):

```
var element= document.getElementById("elementID");
element.innerHTML = someHTMLstring;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = jsVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note that you'll have to use `\n` instead of linebreaks in JavaScript:

```
var jsVar = '<div>\n<p> Sample text </p>\n<img src="some image.jpg"  alt="" />\n<div>';
```

If you don't do this, you'll get a "`unterminated string literal`" error.

Comment: yes ..I am having issues doing that ..replacing all the line feeds with \n

Comment: If you're doing innerHTML, you don't have to have the '\n's, because they're superfluous then.

Answer (score 0):

The string you're assigning, can't span multiple lines:

this doesn't work

```
ttt = "ab
c";
```

this does

```
ttt = "ab" +
      "c";
```

best would be escaping all the special characters, and getting rid of line feeds in your string (I don't like strings done with ', although it's a personal thing :).

```
var jsVar = "<div><p> Sample text </p> <img src=\"some image.jpg\"  alt=\"\" /><div>";
```

Comment: Just a head's up, you can edit your own posts to extend your answer.  (I did so just to cover this situation, in fact.)

Comment: could u elaborate on how I could escaping all the special characters,
 and getting rid of line feeds. Thanks